# Ejabberd chat room message count visibility

Tags: ejabberd

Users are only seeing messages posted in a group chat for only last two days or so(count is less than 30). Is there a config setting that can control how many messages from the past (or in number) can be shown in a chat room when a user connects to it? In ejabberd.yml I only see a setting *max_user_offline_messages* under access has a value of 1000 for all. Also mod_muc has a setting *access_max_user_messages: max_user_offline_messages*

Is there another setting that controls this functionality?

We are using ejabberd version 16.02.79

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you refer to the room recent history. The number can be configured with this option:

> history_size: Size: A small history of the current discussion is sent
>   to users when they enter the room. With this option you can define the
>   number of history messages to keep and send to users joining the room.
>   The value is an integer. Setting the value to 0 disables the history
>   feature and, as a result, nothing is kept in memory. The default value
>   is 20. This value is global and thus affects all rooms on the service.